# bootstrap input in navbar with selectize.js not expanding

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js

I am trying to make the selectize.js input in the navbar bigger, but the selectize's css is applied and it ignores input-large classes. I tried to set even manually the style width for the element but it gets overwritten.

navbar and buttons are standard bootstrap:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a  href="#profile">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#browse">Browse</a></li>

            <li id="friendRequests" class="dropdown"><a id="anw" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-lg"></i>

            </a>
                <ul  class="dropdown-menu">

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a id ="messagesLink" href="#messages"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i>                  
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="" placeholder="search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default color3">Go</button>
            </form>
            <img  src="" class="img-responsive navbar-brand">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a >Settings</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

then I just fire up selectize.js :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#searchBox').selectize({
            valueField: 'tagName',
            labelField: 'tagName',
            searchField: 'tagName',
            maxItems: 1,
   load: function(query, callback) {                                 }});
});
```

A problem that the input shows higher than the button was fixed by commenting out the overflow as suggested in selectize's github as follows:

```
    .selectize-input {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
/*  overflow: hidden;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
```

but I am not sure what property I should change to make the input bigger.

you can take a look at the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/arisalexis/rncujmnk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to increase the width of the searchbox input.

The input you see is created by the selectize.js . You therefore can't control the size by adding classes to you input in your html. Instead you have to target the dynamically added input via CSS like this:

```
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input input {
    width: 150px!important;
}
```

You need to use the `!important` to overwrite the width added via the script. Adjust the `width` according to your needs.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rncujmnk/1/)